# What is the expected packet loss with scapy?

Tags: python, networking, scapy

I want to listen to packets on an interface of `SystemA`. Since it looks like I do not see the vast majority of incoming packets, I used `scapy` in its simplest form:

```
import scapy.all as scapy

def filtre(p):
    if p.haslayer(scapy.IP):
        print(p[scapy.IP].src)

# Disable scapy verbosity
scapy.conf.verb = 0
scapy.sniff(iface="eth0", prn=filtre, store=0)
```

This is ran on `SystemA` with the output sent to a file.

At the same time, I run

- `tcpdump` on `SystemA` and `SystemB`
- `nmap SystemA -P0` on `SystemB`

The idea is to see how many packets, during the `nmap` session leave `SystemB`and reach `SystemA`. The results are

- according to the two `tcpdump`, 1000 packets left `SystemB`and reached `SystemA`
- but there was **only about 150 to 200 packets** with the source IP of `SystemB` registered by `scapy` on `SystemA`

I did several tests, with the `tcpdump` sessions and without (they did not change the result AFAICT), and get a varying number of packets via `scapy` - in the 150-200 range.

This is on a LAN, `SystemB` is a debian, `SystemA` a RPi3. I could expect some packet not to be registered but not 80 to 90%. At the same time `tcpdump` systematically registers the expected 1000 packets on both systems.

Is there something I am missing?

EDIT: the same test with 50 packets (`nmap SystemA -p1-50 -P0`) is fine, scapy registers all 50 packets.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try with something that does not use the output (as this can be a bottleneck). Also, you can use a BPF filter in case you have unwanted packets on the wire. Moreover, since you don't need to dissect the IP payloads, you can prevent Scapy from parsing the whole packet layers.

```
from collections import Counter
import scapy.all as scapy

sources = Counter()

def count_pkts(p):
    global sources
    if scapy.IP in p:
        sources[p[scapy.IP].src] += 1

# Disable scapy verbosity
scapy.conf.verb = 0
# Prevent Scapy from dissecting IP payloads
scapy.IP.payload_guess = []
# Optionally, use filter="ip and src x.y.z.t"
scapy.sniff(iface="eth0", prn=count_pkts, store=0, filter="ip")
print sources
```